# Let $V=\{a_2x^2 + a_1x + 2 : a_1, a_2 \in \mathbb R\}$. How to prove whether this is a vector space or not?

Tags: linear-algebra

I understand and know all the axioms, but applying it becomes difficult in certain questions, like how to solve this question. I think it’s a vector space but I’m not sure about the answer.

Comment: Welcome to MSE. Your question is phrased as an isolated problem, without any further information or context. This does not match [many users' quality standards](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/q/9201), so it may attract downvotes, or be closed. To prevent that, please [edit] the question. [This](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/q/9959) will help you recognize and resolve the issues. Concretely: please provide context, and include your work and thoughts on the problem. These changes can help in formulating more appropriate answers.

Comment: Of cource not....